# cqlsh TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)

Tags: cassandra, cqlsh

When trying to cqlsh, following error is occuring:

`Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'localhost': TypeError('ref() does not take keyword arguments',)})`

Answer (score 11):

This happens when you have Cassandra 3.7 and Python 2.7.12

As per [CASSANDRA-11850](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11850), set following environment variable:

`CQLSH_NO_BUNDLED=TRUE`

Comment: now I get `Python Cassandra driver not installed, or not on PYTHONPATH.
You might try "pip install cassandra-driver".
`